# How to set value on react-dropdown-tree-select component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dropdown-tree-select

I am using TreeSelect component  from [react-dropdown-tree-select](https://github.com/dowjones/react-dropdown-tree-select#react-dropdown-tree-select) . I don't see a value prop on the component. Can someone tell me how to set value on the component so that it will be in selected state

Comment: Hi everyone, anyone still struggling with this problem, I would suggest switch to antd treeselect as it is well documented and maintained. https://ant.design/components/tree-select

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the value from a DropdownTreeSelect component in React JS, you need to use the onChange event and the value prop.

First, you need to create a state variable to hold the selected value. You can use the useState hook to do this:

In the example above, the selectedValue state variable is initialized to an empty string. The handleChange function is called whenever the user selects an option in the dropdown, and it updates the selectedValue state variable with the new selection.

The value prop is then set to the selectedValue state variable, which means that the DropdownTreeSelect component will display the currently selected value.

You can then use the selectedValue state variable in other parts of your component or pass it to other components as a prop.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import DropdownTreeSelect from 'react-dropdown-tree-select';

function MyComponent() {
  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState('');

  function handleChange(currentNode, selectedNodes) {
    setSelectedValue(selectedNodes);
  }

  return (
    <DropdownTreeSelect
      data={...} // pass in your data as props
      onChange={handleChange}
      value={selectedValue}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: I switched to antd TreeSelect as I felt its a better one.